# Чи правильніше «переходити на посилання» замість «переходити за посиланням»?

Tags: вживання-слів, граматика, прийменники

Читав недавно працю Святослава Караванського «У пошуках українського слова», де він навів словничок-рятівничок від «закання»;  закання — це надмірне вживання прийменника «за», зумовлене повсюдним перекладом російського «по» ним. Після його перегляду я задумався над тим, чи не є вжиток «за» у фразі «переходити за посиланням» закальною формою, адже у [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/Za) не зазначено такого вжитку. На жаль, у словничку не зазначено цього словосполучення, а про закання загалом написано вкрай мало. За закономірністю творення українських форм у словничку можна скласти таку форму: «переходити на посилання».

Тож чи міг би хтось сказати, чи правильніше вживати «переходити на посилання» замість «за посиланням»?

Comment: Можливо можна підійти з іншого боку. Якщо розглядати посилання як дорогу, то *пройдіть посиланням*, а якщо розглядати посилання як двері, то *перейдіть через посилання*.

Comment: Але навіщо, коли треба визначити правильну форму?

Comment: А хто як не ми визначає яка форма правильна? Чому за взірець ми взяли російське *перейти по ссьілке*, а не англійське *follow the link*? Чи може це може бути щось інше, як-от *пройдіть через посилання*? До речі, мені ще й *посилання* не подобається, бо має відтінок процесу, але поки нічого іншого на думку не спало.

Comment: знаю, як вам би хотілося якнайдалі відійти від російських форм, але це слід робити мовознавчо, а не на власний розсуд.

Comment: "Переходити на сторінку за посиланням", "Тиснути на посилання для переходу до сторінки".  Як пояснив Yola, це випливає з семантичної ознаки: "Слідувати за посиланням".

Comment: То можете написати це у відповіді з джерелами будь ласка?

Comment: @meleten, гарну відповідь вам вже надав Sasha. Не вбачаю жодного зиску з дублювання інформації. Щоб ваше запитання відповідало стандартам якості, які намагаються підтримувати редактори цього ресурсу, будь ласка, наведіть декілька прикладів використання (бажано від десяти і більше) наведеного вами словотвору в простому оповідальному і питальному реченні.

Comment: @Skill, коментар meleten з проханням «написати це у відповіді з джерелами» з'явився ще до того, як з'явилася моя відповідь. Окрім того «гарна» — це суб'єктивно, запитувач цілком має право бути незадоволеним відповіддю і прагнути іншої, не відмовляймо йому в цьому праві. А приклади використання — це дуже правильно… але навіщо аж десять? Мені здається, що 2-3 у цьому випадку цілком достатньо (от якби мова була про зовсім різні значення слова/словосполучення і для кожного були б потрібні свої приклади, тоді разом би справді могло набратися багацько).

Comment: (Особисто я давно вже схиляюся до думки, що нам варто ставати «інклюзивнішими» — суворі вимоги відлякують потенційних учасників. @Skill, вибачте, якщо Ви теж колись потрапили під жернова нашої прискіпливості.)

Comment: Мені треба додати приклади словотвору Караванського (тобто українські форми до закання), чи просто приклади вживання «за посиланням»?

Comment: @meleten, Українська мова невпинно розвивається протягом сотень років. Від покоління до покоління носіїв вона змінюється, вбирає в себе інші мови і трансформується у щось нове. Та характерною ознакою завжди була її милозвучність. Українська мова ллється немовби пісня і зачаровує своїм звучанням. Саме тому в питанні "правильно чи не правильно", "можна чи не можна" такий важливий контекст. Бо те що дозволено в літературному стилі, зазвичай має обмеження в діловому. Приклади вжитку дозволяють на слух відрізнити "звучить" воно чи "не звучить".

Comment: неправда, бо за радянського союзу українську уподібнювали до російської та викорінювали наші питомі риси. І що важливо, *їм це частково вдалося*. Вони змогли викорінити з нашого усного вжитку такі слова як «захопливий» та «зникомий» на користь «захоплюючий та «зникаючий». Тож якщо з усіма цими *давай/давайте*, *у мене є*, *у першу чергу* розвивається приміром форма «співпадати», це є чужа українська мова.

Answer (score 3):

*Посилання* — це ***вказівник**, позначка, орієнтир, (дорожній) знак, маршрут*.

Відповідно, *«переходити **за** посиланням»*, за аналогією до *«прямувати **за** вказівником»*.

---

По-перше, саме явище гіперпосилання є новим, тому не є словниковим.

Менше з тим, цілком слушно спертися на аналогії, такі як вказівники, орієнтири, в тому числі дорожні знаки.

*Переходити за посиланням* подібне до:
*слідувати, дотримуватися, керуватися, дослухатися* (вказівників, позначок, маршрутів, дорожніх знаків, порад, прикладів, тощо).

[СУМ: *слідувати*](http://sum.in.ua/s/sliduvaty):

> *перен.* Керуватися у чому-небудь чиїмсь прикладом, брати щось за зразок.
> хоче підкреслити в богоматері не божественне, а людське, **слідуючи** в цьому **за** Шевченковою поемою «Марія» (Степан Крижанівський, М. Рильський, 1960, 145).

Вжиток:

- [*Вони взяли з собою дари - золото, ладан і смирну й рушили в путь, слідуючи **за** різдвяною зорею, яка й привела мандрівників до печери, в якій Діва Марія народила Ісуса.*](https://www.ukrinform.ua/rubric-society/1936530-sogodni-katolitske-rizdvo.html)
- [*Пройдіть **за** маршрутом та запишіть відповіді*](https://znanija.com/task/37978931)
- [*Прямуємо **за** вказівниками на Хмельницький*](http://hmeleva.com.ua/index.php/kontakty/8-marshrut-do-khmelevoi) […];
- [*повернути **за** вказівниками гірськолижного комплексу*](https://turizm-karpaty.com.ua/chan-u-kotedzhi-lisovij-zrub-migove/)  […];

Comment: Уточню, що посилання зовсім необов'язково _гіпер-_, вони цілком можуть бути й у текстовому вигляді (наприклад: _Проблеми організаційного забезпечення лікування / І. М. Горбатюк та ін. // Український пульмонологічний журнал. — 2007. — № 4. — С. 21—23_). Тому, по-моєму, явище не таке вже й нове. З рештою згоден.

Comment: але на ваше посилання (що насправді примітка) ніхто не переходить, це геть не те саме, що гіперпосилання. Тому чи варто мені уточнити у моєму запитанні яке посилання я маю на увазі?

Answer (score 2):

Я проти варіанта *перехід на посилання*.

По-моєму, не варто ототожнювати *ресурс*, куди веде посилання, і саме *посилання*:
[image]
Ми переходимо **на ресурс Б** (**до ресурсу Б**, **у ресурс Б** тощо); але ми робимо це **за посиланням** (**відповідно до посилання**, **згідно з посиланням**, **посиланням**, **через посилання** тощо).

Словник дає відповідні значення для прийменника *[за](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=27400&page=918)*, зокрема:

> 12. *з оруд. в*. Уживається при вказуванні на те, згідно з чим, відповідно до чого відбувається дія. *Всі запорожці за цим знаком поскидали свої шапки, потупивши очі в землю, як завжди велося між козаками, коли мав промовляти старший* (О. Довженко); *Новаків вишикували за ранжиром* (С. Добровольський); *Після розговіння, за традицією, належався заслужений відпочинок* (У. Самчук); *Кошовий не пугукав за звичаєм перед воротами міста* (Р. Іваничук).

Точніша схема має такий вигляд:
[image]
— тобто посилання є *частиною* ресурсу А. Але це ще більше підкреслює різницю між посиланням і ресурсом Б.

Comment: Але ж коли кажуть *перейти за посиланням*, люди не мають на увазі ресурс, а тільки перехід на так би мовити «берег», чим є посилання. Тобто мало би бути *переходити на посилання*.

Comment: @meleten, вибачте, я не розумію… Можете пояснити, у чому різниця між «ресурсом» і «берегом» у Вашій термінології?

Comment: @meleten, P.S., у випадку гіперпосилання (не певен, що Ви питаєте саме про нього, але все-таки…) _перейти на посилання_, по-моєму, теж можливо, але це означатиме, як на мене, «фокусувати посилання», а не «слідувати за ним». Тобто коли кілька разів натиснули _Tab_, щоб «виділити» посилання, але так і не натиснули _Enter_. Але, по-моєму, це доволі рідкісний випадок, тому я не згадував про нього в моїй відповіді (у моїй спробі відповіді).

Comment: @meleten, Перейти на посилання неможливо, бо воно лише вказує на ресурс (під'єднану бібліотеку, шрифт, зовнішній або внутрішній скрипт,  поточну або іншу веб-сторінку, тощо) але не містить його!

Comment: @Sasha, можливо, вашу відповідь можна покращити з використанням оригінальної статі, яка доступна за ось цим посиланням https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink

Comment: @Skill, «лише вказує на ресурс, але не містить його» — дякую, от саме це я й намагався сформулювати у своїй відповіді, але у Вас вишло лаконічніше!

Comment: @Skill, «за ось цим посиланням en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink» — або за цим: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation. Фактично в українському _посилання_ поєднуються обидва значення: citation і hyperlink. Спочатку (до появи hyperlink'ів) _посилання_ означало citation, а потім його значення розширилося і до hyperlink.